# pl/sql project password change

Tags: oracle, plsql, change-password

this is my first pl/sql database project, so I am not experienced but need to start somewhere, I am writing a procedure for a update statement of customer table cpw which the user need to enter the username, if that match the cusername column the they will enter the old password, if that match with the cpw of the same row, then the system will update the new password which is prompt and accepted. here's what i have so far. any help will be appreciated.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Changepassword (input_cusername IN VARCHAR, 
                                            old_cpw         IN VARCHAR, 
                                            new_cpw OUT VARCHAR) 
IS 
  DECLARE 
    c_username customer.cusername%TYPE; 
    c_cpw customer.cpw%TYPE; 
  BEGIN 
    ACCEPT input_cusername VARCHAR(40) prompt 'Username: ' 
    ACCEPT old_cpw         VARCHAR(20) prompt 'Enter Your Old Password:' 
    ACCEPT new_cpw         VARCHAR(20) prompt 'Enter Your New Password:' 
    UPDATE customer 
    SET    cpw = new_cpw 
    WHERE  cusername = input_cusername; 

  EXCEPTION 
  WHEN input_cusername <> c_username customer.cusername%TYPE THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('no such user exist'); 
  WHEN old_cpw <> cpw FROM customer WHERE cusername = input_cusername THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('Password Incorrect'); 
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your `procedure`.

1. `new_cpw` should be an `IN` parameter.
2. Better use `VARCHAR2` data type.

> ```
> create or replace procedure changePassword (input_cusername IN VARCHAR2, 
>                                             old_cpw         IN VARCHAR2, 
>                                             new_cpw         IN VARCHAR2)
> ```

3. `DECLARE` your own `EXCEPTION` and `user-defined error` message using `raise_application_error`.

> ```
> wrong_username EXCEPTION;
> wrong_password EXCEPTION;
> ```

4. You MUST first `validate` the `USERNAME` entered.
5. If username is incorrect, then `RAISE` an `EXCEPTION` for `wrong_username EXCEPTION`.
6. If `cusername entered is valid, i.e. if it exists in the table, then verify the`old password` entered is correct.

> ```
> SELECT cpw 
>   INTO var_password 
> FROM customer 
>  WHERE cusername = input_cusername;
>
> IF UPPER(old_cpw) = UPPER(var_password)
> THEN
>    UPDATE customer SET cpw = new_cpw WHERE cusername = input_cusername;
> ELSE 
>    RAISE wrong_password;
> END IF;
> ```

7. Handle the `exceptions` gracefully.

> ```
> EXCEPTION 
>    WHEN wrong_username THEN
>       raise_application_error (-20001,'You have entered an incorrect username');
>    WHEN wrong_password THEN
>       raise_application_error (-20001,'You have entered an incorrect password');
> ```

8. You MUST always have validations on the `password security` and levy some `password rules`. For example, `LENGTH` of password etc.

Comment: Some of these issues are really not important and are not "wrong". For example, it's not "wrong" to use VARCHAR, and it's not "wrong" to fail to validate the username. In fact, his original code *does* validate the username already. Also, it's not true that he "MUST" always validate password security or levy password rules. Just a suggestion to revise your answer down to the important points.

Comment: T, how would you link the username validation step and old_password validation together, I tried nested if then statements but it didn't work. I will work on exception after I get the body to work first, here's what I have:

Comment: ACCEPT p_cusername PROMPT 'Enter Customer User Name: '
DECLARE
     v_cusername VARCHAR(40);
     v_cpw VARCHAR(40)
BEGIN
     SELECT cusername INTO v_cusername
            FROM customer
     WHERE cusername = '&p_cusername';
     IF 
     v_cusername = '&p_cusername'
     THEN
      ACCEPT p_cpw PROMPT 'Enter Customer Password: '
        SELECT cpw into v_cpw
            FROM customer
        WHERE cpw = '&p_cpw';
          IF
          v_cpw = '&p_cpw'
        THEN
          UPDATE CUSTOMER SET CPW = '&new_password' WHERE CUSERNAME = v_cusername;
      END IF;
    END IF;
END;

Answer (score 0):

Although there are a few minor issues with your code (such as those pointed out by Lalit), the main thing you need to address first is what you actually want this code to do.

You have mixed some `ACCEPT` commands in your PL/SQL, but these are SQL*Plus commands that are only intended for interactive scripts; they cannot be included within PL/SQL. PL/SQL is not an interactive language; it is designed to be called from some other process (whether from within an interactive SQL*Plus script, or from a front-end interface such as Apex).

Comment: yes, Jeffery, the code is meant to work under SQL developer application, the heart of the procedure need to do is 
update customer set cpw = 'userinput_new_cpw' where cusuername = 'input cusername';
accept command were the only command I can think of would make that work, but I am having trouble with the order of it and how to pass the input value into the select statement

Comment: SQL Developer, as the name suggests, is a developer tool. You wouldn't normally design end-user processes requiring it.